# ReactJs with ASP.NET Web API multiple External authentication providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a ReactJs application with a Web API backend. Authentication is handled at the WebAPI side using external login providers (Google, Facebook and a custom SAML provider).

After successful authentication, the server receives the request and is able to extract access tokens, claims etc.

What is the best strategy for securing the communication between React and the WebAPI? Should the WebAPI also act as an oauth server, or should the request with the access token just be redirected to React so it can parse the body and extract the tokens.